# Objective-C save NSColor in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, save, nsuserdefaults, nscolor

How do you save the color of the dot so that when the app is opened and closed the dot is the color it was last set to by the user?

Could someone explain to me how to use `NSUserDefaults` and in which methods to declare `NSUserDefaults`.

So far i have this:

```
NSData *data = [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"MyColor"];

NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyColor"];
NSColor *color = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Link for tutorial I followed:
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.25/25.04/2504RoadtoCode/index.html

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking. Your code above looks fine (except you should probably add a cast to (NSColor *) before the unarchive). What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The app displays a circle who's color is controlled by a color well, what I want do is, when the color well is selected and a new color is chosen I want to save that new color and set the circle to that color. Then when the app is reopened again I want to set the color of the circle to the saved color.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use:

```
- (NSColor *)colorForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData  *data;
    NSColor *color;

    data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
    color= [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    if( ! [color isKindOfClass:[NSColor class]] )
    {
        color = nil;
    }

    return color;
    }

- (void)setColor:(NSColor *)color forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *data = [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:key];

    [BFChatWindow refresh];
}
```

Comment: It isn't the Dvorak that causes problems (as I use it) but the tabs instead of spaces in your code formatting.

Comment: @Abizern When I copy paste it doesn't work, that is the problem with dvorak and stack overflow

Comment: @Abizern its probably because I use Dvorak - Qwerty, dvorak  typing layout but qwerty cmd + whatever  -- easier as most commands are meant for the qwerty layout